# Macbook 13" mid 2010 wifi card BCM432b not working...Tried every guide in this forum

Tags: wireless, power-management, broadcom, macbook, macbook-pro

I recently clean installed LXLE 16.04 at my MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010

Going through the previously asked questions I followed [this guide here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) till the end.

Disabled (purged) the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver and installed the `firmware-b43-installer` as recommended.

Followed the:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

commands.

I blacklisted everything that has to do with bcm43 in `blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist bcma
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

And added `rfkill unblock wifi` in `/etc/rc.local`

Still my Macbook Pro wifi card is occasionally working...(1/3rd of the times)

...usually I see no wifi networks although the card appears active.

I'm using my smartphone USB tethering option to share internet to my laptop.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008d]
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: ssb

Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684]
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg3

VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 [GeForce 320M] [10de:08a0] (rev a2)
```

Any ideas for a linux beginner?

Thank you

**UPDATE 1:** *I think it might have something to do with power management. Quite often when in plug my wifi card scan's and shows the available wifi networks. When on battery , the wifi card is active but not scanning , not showing any available network.*

**UPDATE 2:** *I removed LXLE and clean installed Xubuntu 16.04. Installed 'bcmwl-kernel-source' driver from the "Additional Drivers" section. Still the same problem...the wifi card is installed but it is not scanning for wifi networks.*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Done @Pilot6

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! `bcmwl-kernel-source` is supposedly the correct driver for this wireless chipset according to [Louis' answer](/a/60395/175814). Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) when your wireless card fails and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct driver for this adapter is `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Run

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6

So , I should go back and reverse everything done till now to work with 'bmwl-kernel-source'  instead of  'firmware-b43-installer'  ??

Is it not related with power management at all?

Thank you again , appreciate it.

Comment: Ok followed your advice. Now the wifi card does **not** appear...Ideas? I only see the LAN card after doing 'lspci | grep Network'  .... _(and driver manager LXLE is not loading)_

Comment: Installing the drivers do not affect appearance in lspci.

Comment: Again , couldn't it be a power management issue? As I mentioned earlier the wifi card usually worked when on AC power with the 'firmware-b43-installer' drive.  Wifi didn't work 100% of times when on battery... With 'bcmwl-kernel-source' driver card disappeared from the system....not in networking , not appearing after doing 'lspci'... I will have to argue that this driver just don't work for my system.

Comment: I just edited - updated my main question. Any new ideas? Thank you very much